# Escape character in LIKE within user variable

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to load data from a local file with two columns, one of which isn't inserted directly but mapped to an id found in a lookup table. However, the strings I'm looking for contain an underscore, which is interpreted by `LIKE` and is not the desired effect.

When making a normal query, I would've just escaped `_` with `\_`, but as it's in a user variable, I can't find how to escape this character directly. Take this example, with the following `LOAD DATA` statement:

`LOAD DATA` statement:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'file.csv' INTO TABLE my_table
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
ESCAPED BY ''
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
(@foo, bar)
SET foo = (
  SELECT id FROM lookup_table
  WHERE foo_string
  LIKE @foo
  LIMIT 1
);
```

`file.csv`

```
STR_1   hi
STR_2   hey
```

Table `my_table`

```
+--------+---------+-------+
| id     | foo     | bar   |
+--------+---------+-------+
|      1 |       2 | hello |
|      2 |       1 | world |
+--------+---------+-------+
```

Table `lookup_table`

```
+--------+------------+
| id     | foo_string |
+--------+------------+
|      1 |      STR_1 |
|      2 |      STR_2 |
+--------+------------+
```

In this example, `@foo` is interpreted by `LIKE` as `STR_1` and won't match any entries, I'd like it to be `STR\_1`.

Changing the csv file format is a possibility, by adding an escape character myself, but I want to know if there is a "cleaner" way first.

Answer (score 0):

Well, looks like it does that automatically. I thought that was the culprit to my problem but I had an entirely other issue I didn't see, which can't be seen here but I'll explain what I did anyways.

In my SQL query on my end, I was using `LOAD DATA INFILE ... (@foo, bar) SET foo_id = (SELECT ...)` thinking that `SET` would map `foo_id` to its corresponding column in the table. All it actually does is create an unused user variable named `@foo_id`.

The solution here is to use the exact column name as a user variable everywhere, giving something like `LOAD DATA INFILE ... (@foo_id, bar) SET foo_id = (SELECT ...)`